# don't retry when received NXDOMAIN for a while

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I just installed bind on my qmail server with the goal of avoiding DNS queries for domains that the server already ask a few seconds/minutes ago, as caching server. So now, resolv.conf has 127.0.0.1 as nameserver, and after a while the new local-bind is answering almost every query.

However, I can see (using tcpdump) that the server is still asking for a lot of domain to my primary and secondary DNS servers (Using forward), and just realized this:

DNS query : `MX? hotmeil.com`

DNS answer: `ServFail`

Well, as you can see I'm receiving a `NXDOMAIN` (ServFail)

The question, is it possible to tell my local-DNS to not retry for NXDOMAIN received?, at least remember the fail for a while, and thus avoiding all these useless queries?

Thanks guys!.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I'm receiving a `NOERROR` response, not `NXDOMAIN`.

Comment: You can edit your question to change the context

Answer (score 2):

A `NOERROR` (aka `NODATA`) response means that the domain exists, but that the specific resource record type requested (`MX?`) does not.

Your DNS server *should* wait for the "minttl" time specified in that response before asking again.  This also applies to the `SERVFAIL` response, if seen.  See [RFC 2308](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2308).

Note though that any such TTL is *advisory*.  If your name server runs out of cache it's perfectly free to forget that a record doesn't exist and query for it again when asked.